# Make label same width with below Semantic UI

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

How to make Label and input box to have same width like bootstrap does, currently my page is like this
[image]

```html
<div class="three column row">
  <div class="left floated column">
    <div class="inline fields">
      <label style="width:128px;">Customer Code</label>
      <div class="ui input right icon">
        <i class="search icon"></i>
        <input type="text" id="CustomerCode" class="search" readonly name="card[number]" placeholder="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inline fields">
      <label style="width:128px;">Customer Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="card[number]" placeholder="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right floated column">
    <div class="inline fields">
      <label>Customer Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="card[number]" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <div class="inline fields">
      <label>Phone No</label>
      <input type="text" name="card[number]" placeholder="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: give a class to each of your input tag and use it evertime you need an input feild\

Answer (score 3):

Please try this one.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.3/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<h1>Single</h1>
<div class="ui form">
  <div class="inline field">
  <label style="width:30%; text-align:right;">Last name Test</label>
  <input placeholder="Full Name" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="inline field">
    <label style="width:30%; text-align:right;">Fast name Testing  </label>
    <input placeholder="Full Name" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Please try new code this working fine. now option and no any library in semantic ui so we need to add custom css

Answer (score 0):

This could be one of the easy solution

```css
input[type="text"] {
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="three column row">
  <div class="left floated column">
    <div class="inline fields">
      <label style="width:128px;">Customer Code</label>
      <div class="ui input right icon">
        <i class="search icon"></i>
        <input type="text" id="CustomerCode" class="search" readonly name="card[number]" placeholder="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inline fields">
      <label style="width:128px;">Customer Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="card[number]" placeholder="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right floated column">
    <div class="inline fields">
      <label>Customer Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="card[number]" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <div class="inline fields">
      <label>Phone No</label>
      <input type="text" name="card[number]" placeholder="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Hope this help!

```css
.input{
   display: inline-block;
}
label{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   display: inline-block;
   max-width: 120px;
}
.inline{
   margin:15px 0;
}
 input[type="text"]{
      width: 120px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="three column row">
            <div class="left floated column">
                <div class="inline fields">
                    <label>Customer Code</label>
                    <div class="ui input right icon">
                        <i class="search icon"></i>
                        <input type="text" id="CustomerCode" class="search" readonly name="card[number]" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="inline fields"> 
                    <label>Customer Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="card[number]" placeholder="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="right floated column">
                <div class="inline fields"> 
                    <label>Customer Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="card[number]" placeholder="">
                </div>
                <div class="inline fields"> 
                    <label>Phone No</label>
                    <input type="text" name="card[number]" placeholder="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: better to add some explanation around your answer.